# How to handle unsupported HTTP methods on actions in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I handle requests to actions that exist, but don't support the http method in the request?

For example, I have the following action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/")]
[Route("ServiceVisits")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

If a `GET` request comes to `http://localhost:59949/` or `http://localhost:59949/ServiceVisits` then we get the page back, but if a `POST` request comes, then I get an exception in my `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs` that I have to deal with.

Requests that come to non-existent actions will return a `404` page, because I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PageNotFound",
    "{*.*}",
    new {controller = "Error", action = "NotFound"}
);
```

I'm using Attribute Routing and the above convention is my only one for handling 404's.

I want to log only serious system errors in `Application_Error` and not `No matching action was found on controller` exceptions. Thank you!

Comment: In the `Application_Error` you will get all sort of errors, regardless of how you are handling them. If your concern is simply not to log some specific errors, you could add a check in the `Application_Error` handler.

Comment: @TasosK. Is there no cleaner way of handling http method related 404's? I tried to design my application in a way that only critical server errors would reach `Application_Error` and everything else is handled by filters and such. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to simply check for 404's in `Application_Error` and avoid logging those errors, like so:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (ex is HttpException httpEx)
    {
        var httpCode = httpEx.GetHttpCode();
        Context.Response.StatusCode = httpCode;

        if (httpCode != (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "Unhandled HttpException in Application_Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Logger.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled exception in Application_Error");
    }

    Context.Server.ClearError();
    Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}
```